# File creation writring to the file

Tags: python

I am having difficulty writing some scores to a text file for a game...

```
if total_player1>total_player2:           
    f=open("mydatafilescores.txt","w")

    f.write("The winner of the match was")
    f.write(str(auth_user1))
    f.write("with an outstanding score of")
    f.write(str(total_player1))
    f.close            
print("\nGood Game. Game is over!")
elif total_player2>total_player1:

f=open("mydatafilescores.txt","w")

f.write("The winner of the match was")
f.write(str(auth_user2))
f.write("with an outstanding score of")
f.write(str(total_player2))
f.close            
print("\nGood Game. Game is over!")
```

The variables are already calculated, the problem is that nnothing is appearing inside of the actual text document.The actual indentation is correct in my program, but iv copied it abit weirdly into the stackoverflow website. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It's `f.close()`, not `f.close`.

Comment: As you know, the indentation in your code doesn't make sense. What you've posted will not run. You should correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
f.close
```

to

```
f.close()
```

Or use

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    # your code
```

Comment: @mob Use file.writeline() or file.write("your text \n") if you want to end your line with line break.